# How do I find the intersection of subgraphs in a directed acyclic graph efficiently?

Tags: graphs, parallel-computing

I have a directory structure in which each directory can have multiple parents (IOW, a `cd ..` is ambiguous).  AFAICS this means this is equivalent to a directed acyclic graph.

Now, a set of directories (aka vertices) is given.  I need to know all directories which are below all of those given directories.  Thus, I need the intersection of subgraphs.

In my case, getting the set of sub-directories is a rather costly operation.  However, I can do it in parallel, i.e. I can do `ls` on multiple directories at the same time.

While one can easily think of a brute-force algorithm to do that (collect all vertices in sets, find the intersection of the sets) I wonder whether these is a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Intersection not union? Probably you could save a bit when there are folders that are parents to multiple directories, but in general case how can you add all vertices without reading directories?

Comment: Yes, intersection.  And yes, for adding all vertices to sets if would have to read all directories, at least once.  This means, if one “crawler” has already seen a directory that another crawler hits, the latter can stop crawling this branch.

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient algorithm you're looking for is breadth/depth-first search.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important element in my question – the part about costs and parallelism.  It may affect your answer, I haven't yet searched for your keywords.

Comment: That doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Care to elaborate? The most efficient algorithm I can think of right now can still visit subbranches multiple times. If I try a bit of dynamic programming and save the visited directories as a bitset for each node, then I run out of memory.